# How can I share my terminal through a web browser?

Tags: gratis, linux, web-apps, command-line

I'm looking to share my bash shell with the world or maybe just a local network through a web browser. I'm aware I can use emulators such as [`ShellInABox`](https://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/), but I'm looking for more of a read-only interface. Sort of like Twitch but for terminal.

Use case could be something like this:

```
startserver localhost:8080
```

then terminal session proceeds as per normal, but all output and commands are broadcast in real time through a locally hosted server. Visitors to the `8080` port should be able to view the session.

Ideally, this should run with minimum overhead and in CSS/JS without any Java applets, flash plugins or other add-ons. I'm looking for a Debian solution, if that's relevant.

I've included a possible application below as an answer, but I'm open to more suggestions, especially since GoTTY seems to be more targeted at OSX than Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [GoTTY](http://gotty.io/)

[image: screenshot]

> GoTTY is a simple command line tool that turns your CLI tools into web applications.

GoTTY is available through HomeBrew

```
brew tap yudai/gotty
brew install gotty
```

There's a [`tar`](https://github.com/yudai/gotty/releases) available for Linux users as well.